# C++ linked list big call number Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, list, fault

i was create linked list and now i have problem when i want to find specific data in my list: Example i insert in my list 200 000 strings and when i call list->at(1) (1 id is last string in list) i got Segmentation fault, if i call list->at(100 000) it work perfect
My code  is:

stringList.h:

```
#ifndef STRINGLIST_H
#define STRINGLIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class stringList
{
    public:
        stringList();
        virtual ~stringList();
        void insert(string *newString);
        void insert(string newString);
        int size();
        string at(int poz);
        void display();
        void clear();    
    protected:
    private:
        string* atP(int *poz);
        stringList *itsList;
        string *itsString;
        int *sizeString;
        string  *buff;
        //staticint *sizeString;
        int *itsPoz;
};

#endif // STRINGLIST_H
```

stringList.cpp:

```
#include "stringList.h"    
stringList::stringList()
{
    itsList=0;
    itsString=0;
    sizeString=0;    
    itsPoz=new int(0);
    buff=new string;
}    
stringList::~stringList()
{
    delete sizeString;
    sizeString=0;
    delete itsPoz;
    itsPoz=0;
    delete buff;
    buff=0;
    delete itsString;
    itsString=0;
}
void stringList::insert(string *newString){
    if(!sizeString){    
        sizeString=new int(0);
    }    
    if(!sizeString){
        sizeString=new int(0);
    }    
    stringList *newList=new stringList;
    stringList *tmp=new stringList;
    if(itsList){
        *sizeString=*itsList->itsPoz+1;    
        tmp=this->itsList;
        this->itsList=newList;
        this->itsList->itsString=newString;
        *this->itsList->itsPoz=*sizeString;
        this->itsList->itsList=tmp;    
    }else{
        this->itsList=newList;
        this->itsList->itsString=newString;
        *this->itsList->itsPoz=0;    
    }    
}
void stringList::insert(string newString){    
    string *p_string=new string;
    if(!sizeString){
        sizeString=new int(0);
    }    
    *p_string=newString;
    stringList *newList=new stringList;
    stringList *tmp=new stringList;
    if(itsList){
        *sizeString=*itsList->itsPoz+1;    
        tmp=this->itsList;
        this->itsList=newList;
        this->itsList->itsString=p_string;
        *this->itsList->itsPoz=*sizeString;
        this->itsList->itsList=tmp;    
    }else{
        this->itsList=newList;
        this->itsList->itsString=p_string;
        *this->itsList->itsPoz=0;   
    }    
}    
int stringList::size(){
    if(sizeString)
    return *sizeString+1;
    else
        return 0;   
}
string stringList::at(int poz){    
    if(!sizeString){
            return "NEMA LISTE";    
    }
    if(poz>*sizeString){
        return "";
    }    
    buff=this->atP(&poz);   
    return *buff;    
}
string* stringList::atP(int *poz){    
    if(*this->itsList->itsPoz==*poz){    
            return this->itsList->itsString;    
    }
    else{    
        return this->itsList->atP(poz);    
    }    
}
void stringList::display(){    
    if(this->itsList){
        this->itsList->display();
    }
    if(itsString){
        cout<<*itsString<<" , "<<*itsPoz<<endl;    
    }    
}
void stringList::clear(){    
        if(this->itsList->itsList){
            this->itsList->clear();
        }
        delete itsList;
        delete sizeString;
        sizeString=0;
        itsList=0;   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that when you post code here, you remove multiple  consecutive blank lines. I makes for a lot more scrolling to see the entire code.

Comment: When you have a segfault, there should be a core file generated. You can look at this core file (on linux, it is done with gdb) and see which where it did core.

Comment: Is there a very good reason, not to use std::list, and reinvent the wheel again, but a square one this time?

Comment: I learn to programming and i need to learn how to make my linked list. I need to understand this problem.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add static member: pointers to first and last elements. They are veru useful for many things

And what kind og segmetation fault is it? The execption protected mode produces when a thread tries to access memory that is has not got the explicit right to?

If nr 2, then there is a bug in your code. Check bounds and stuff like that.

You want to see a simple linked list I will write on the fl that work well?

Comment: Why on earth would those be static? That would hinder the use of more than one list.

Comment: Yeah, youre right. Make them non static and make sure that they are only set when appropiate, if the listen is tom and m_pRoot = NULL, for example.

Comment: I got Segmentation fault when i call stringList.at(bigger then 174600 number) when number is smaller then this it works perfect, but if is bigger then i got Segmentation fault.

Comment: When you remove an entry, do you do connect this->last = this->next and decrease size by one?

Comment: I did not make function to remove specific entry, but i can clear all of them, and while is clear process i decrease size buy one till i finally delete it.
I thin this is problem with stack memory, cus every time i call function cpu save current instruction  pointer value in stack, and i spent all stack with my recursion function. I think that is great idea to make static list that save every 50K node, and when i call big node to call that pointer.
Thanks every one for help

Comment: Remember you cannot access ONE byte that is no allocated to you in protected mode, that is the source of a a lot of crap bugs

Answer (score 0):

In `stringList::at` you're calling `stringList::atP` which calls `stringList::at`. This leads to recursion and most likely a stack overflow, which then terminates the programm with a segfault. you might change this to an iterative way, something along the lines of

```
 list = this;
 do {
     if (itsPoz==poz) { /* found */ } 
 } while (list = this->itsList);
```

But the code has a lot of other issues (never do `using namespace std;` in global scope in a header, you're apparently are storing pointers without ownership guarantees (i.e. sing smart pointers), etc.)

Comment: my function at call atp and atp is recursion that call it self. I use that function to pass pointer not value.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you recurse and that exceeds the stack, so at some point the stack is exceeded and can't further recurse. So either you limit your list's length or don't use recursion.